# Can the Cloud Foundry Maven Plugin Work With Multi-Module Aggregator Projects?

Tags: maven-3, cloud-foundry

I have a standard multi-module maven project and I'm able to build it locally using `mvn clean package`but when I try to deploy it using $ mvn cf:update I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.0.0.M2:update (default-cli) on project <myprojectname>: An exception was caught while executing Mojo. The file or directory does not exist at '<my project directory>/target/<myprojectname>-SNAPSHOT.war'. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.0.0.M2:update
```

The problem is that I can't build a .war file for my parent .pom because it needs to be packaged as a pom file, or else maven will reject it.  Therefore, I cannot supply the .war file cloudfoundry is looking for.   Is there a setting I'm missing?

I'm currently looking into the Maven assembly plugin, but it seems like there should be a more straightforward way to push a multi-module maven project using the maven cloud foundry plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your parent root either has a single parent pom file or if its a module, it only has a pom inside the target. You are not creating war file inside the target root of your project (if target even exist there). Your application is most likely having each module create their own war files inside their target folders.

At this time I don't think the cf maven plugin would support what you are looking for. could be a enhancement to add a parameter with the module that contains the war file but that is something that needs to be done!

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java-client/blob/master/cloudfoundry-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/maven/Update.java

I would recommend you to look into the assembly plugin (which you are already).

Let us know how it goes!